# Interesting: How to achieve this product catalogue effect

Tags: catalog, layered-navigation

Can anybody let me know how to achieve this effect with Magento.

This effect based on catalogue or folder wise structure of products.
The main catalogue or folder shows the image itself alongwith total number of products inside it.

After clicking on any of the folder all the products related to that can be seen.
This is even based on layered navigation based.
It is very much convenient for customers to browse the collection.
They can even find their product once they come back again.

The standalone link of those products is also there on the site by which direct browsing of those products can be possible from under their main categories.

I am providing the links of both way.
1.
http://www.utsavfashion.in/store/variety.aspx?cat=salwar

Below is the link under main category salwar kameez (where all the products can be seen and can be filtered using multiple checkbox layered navigation filter in the left side)
2. http://www.utsavfashion.in/store/items.aspx?cat=salwar

I am sure everybody will like this and want this in their own site.
Even developers and programmers would like to use and merge this feature in their Themes and Magento default features.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

After a bit browsing, I found that there are few extensions out there in the market for multi-select checkbox layered navigation filter that can be used for point number 2
However, I am yet to find out the option for point number 1